# How to get BeanPostProcessor object in springboot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I know how to use BeanPostProcessor object in SpringBoot, but how can I get the object of BeanPostProcessor?

Answer (score 0):

BeanPostProcessor is just an interface, there can be multiple implementations of such interface in your project.

You should be able to retrieve a specific bean post-processor as you would with any other bean, eg.:

```java
@Autowired
private MySpecificBeanPostProcessor beanPostProcessor;
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean? If you want to get all post processors you can inject `List<BeanPostProcessor>` into your bean. If you want one specific bean you can precise it with `@Bean` or `@Qualifier` annotations.